# Auto register software after every reboot

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I have a software which was originally purchased for Windows Vista and ran well on that system.

After upgrading to Windows 10, I find that I need to register the software on each reboot. Since the maker of software already went under, I can not find any support from them.

So I need help to solve this problem, i.e. how to make it register automatically after every boot. Thanks.

Comment: Why not run the software in a Windows 7 VM?

Comment: or try running it compatibility mode

Comment: I need to run it in Windows 10 without affecting other apps.